# Can't review closed votes, but still 20 votes left

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

I was helping to burn the close vote queue and I was surprised to see the "you reached 40 closed votes today, come back in xx hours" message so soon. Now, I discover I still had 20 close votes left! What's going wrong?

[image: review blocked]
[image: still 18 left]

Please note that I've already done 2 close votes after the review was blocked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The remaining close votes can be used directly on a question, not in the queue (this will however fill the queue).